# Will compiler optimize away called-once functions

Tags: compilation, language-agnostic

I've been reading "Clean Code" by Robert C Martin, and one of the pieces of advice is to use more but smaller functions; i.e. instead of

```
int main(){

    // do one thing
    // ... 10 lines of code

    // do another thing
    // ... another 10 lines of code

    // one last thing
    // ... another 10 lines

    return 0;
}
```

you ought to

```
int main(){
    doOneThing();
    doAnotherThing();
    oneLastThing();
}

void doOneThing(){
    ... 10 lines of code
}

// ... you get the idea
```

However, from my understanding of low level langauges, I know that when a function is called, variables are pushed onto the stack and the stack pointer is incremented, etc, whereas for the continuous code, there is no need to do this.

On the other hand, compiler optimisations can do cool things like inline class methods. Assuming `doOneThing` is called exactly once, could a compiler this code, deduce that the code can be unrolled into `main()`, and elimiate the function call and associated runtime overhead altogether?

Comment: compilers can and do inline functions when they see that it is a performance gain. Calling a function has a cost, but it is far less then 10 lines. You can start to worry when the function is 0 or 1 line

Comment: what did you find when you tried?

Comment: Please pick one language

Comment: There is an well known issue with programming (programmers) known as Premature Optimisation (you can Google it). It's always better to write clear correct code as a first pass.  Then _"if and only if"_ the code does not meet your performance criteria should you: create benchmarks, then measure and profile.

Comment: one way to see it is separation of concerns (you can google that too ;). A function should do one thing not more. If your function does AB and C, then it is useless whenever you need only A or only B or CBA, or BAC. Though thats only one point, others are readability, easier refactoring, etc

Comment: I missed the retagging :/. Imho this question is not lanugage agnostic. Inlining, possibilities for compiler optimizations, effects of refactoring on runtime efficiency, etc, are very much depending on the used language.

Comment: [language-agnostic] makes the question unanswerable as _"...Will compiler optimize..."_ depends on the language/compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A previous version of the question was about C++ or C. I am convinced that it needs the context of a language to discuss this topic in a meaningful way, so I chose to stay with C++.

C++ is not really "low level". Code you write is not instructions for your CPU. Between your code and what actually happens during runtime there is one of the most sophisticated pieces of software: Your compiler. When you turn on optimizations then your compiler will analyze your code and try to produce the most efficient executable that behaves at runtime as your code would if it was taken literally (i.e. no optimizations).

This is governed by the so-called as-if rule. Calling a function is not observable behavior. If the function is small, the compiler will inline the call to the function.

On the other hand, of course calling a function has a cost, but that cost is comparatively small. You need to start worry about this overhead, when the function is very small, like only 1 or 2 lines, and (and this is important!) for some reason the compiler cannot inline the call. This can be due the function being virtual for example.

You are asking if a compiler can optimize it, so I pick just one example. Gcc with `-O3` will produce following output for following code:

```
int foo() { return 42;}
int bar() { return 0;}
int moo() { return 1;}


int main() {
    return foo() + bar() + moo();
}
```

[output](https://godbolt.org/z/5rdjxTjnq):

```
foo():
        mov     eax, 42
        ret
bar():
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
moo():
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
main:
        mov     eax, 43
        ret
```

You can see hat in `main` no function is called. THe compiler examind the expression `foo() + bar() + moo()` and realized it always equals `43`. No function has to be called to return `43`.

This is a silly example, though for the general case, if you do want to see what the compiler did you need to do the same: look at the compilers output.

And to do that you need to write the code first. It is of no use to first speculate which code would be more efficient or less efficient. You first need to write the code. And because you need to do that anyhow, you can write clean simple human comprehensible code. That's the code your compiler understands best and knows how to optimize, because thats also what other programmers write.